# How do I go about adding dividers for RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, divider

Currently, my RecyclerView is displaying correctly, but does not have dividers between each data set/item.

This is the code I'm using for my RecyclerView, with the layout of the the items displayed in the code snippet below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code which determines how the items are arranged.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group Name"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group Date"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupLocation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Group Location"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/className"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Class Name"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's a picture of what the app looks like, with the RecyclerView:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGfF.jpg

Comment: see `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

Comment: Just set `android:padding="10dp"` to your root layout

Comment: I edited my post slightly. Which one do you mean when you say root layout

Comment: @MehulGoel `padding` has nothing to do with dividers, see `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` for thing like that: "An **ItemDecoration** allows the application to add a special drawing and layout offset to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This can be useful for drawing **dividers between items**, highlights, visual grouping boundaries and more."

Comment: Maybe one sollution is to put a view(line) at the bottom of list item layout.

Comment: @pskink Is that the best way to do it? It seems like a lot of work just to add dividers

Comment: see http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/ ^F divider

Comment: Thanks so much! wasted so much time with this

Answer (score 0):

You can add Divider as below

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration
            (new DividerItemDecoration(MyActivity.this,
                    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
```